# Java-How can I peel off a single char in a String and store them in a 1D array?

Tags: java, string, char

I have a String `"301918574X"` and I want to store each letter into an array with `3` in the first slot, `0` in the second slot, `1` in the third slot, etc.

How would I go about doing this?

### EDIT:

I now have each character assigned to the appropriate array slot. But there is one letter in the array, and that's `"X"` (this is actually an ISBN). When there is an `X`, it should have the value of `10` but obviously that won't work in a character array.

Comment: You shouldn't say `thanks` in prosa, but upvote correct answers, and confirm the best one. A new question should just be that: a new question. You may reference your old question, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
char[] theArrayYouWant = str.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `String.toCharArray()`. As [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) states, "it returns a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of the string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by the string."

The API documentation for the platform should be the first resource to look at when wondering if a class directly supports a specific operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
String testString="301918574X";
char[] resultArray = new char[12];

for (int i=0;i<testString.length();i++)
{
  resultArray[i] = testString.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: And what would the advantage of the loop be over a simple call to `String.toCharArray()`?

Comment: I agree with your answer. From the title of this question "Peel of a single char", i thought he is trying to traverse one by one. But you are right its better to use toCharArray() if all char's are needed and no skipping or processing required.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need indexed access, you can use [`String.charAt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29). If you really need the array, use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

Comment: Amazing. Now my only issue is that since this is an ISBN, X will appear at the end of the String sometimes. Right now, each char is assigned to its correct spot in the array thanks to you guys. But the last char is X and it needs to be given a value 10 so I can do math with it. Unfortunately, since 10 is obviously not a char, I am unable to change X to 10.

Comment: Well, map your char array to an int array using `Integer.parseInt()` (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and handle your special case manually.

Answer (score 0):

To "do Math with" your characters, store them not as `char`, but as `int`.

Here is an example:

```
int[] digits = new int[str.length()];
for(int i : 0; i < str.length -1; i++) {
    digits[i] = Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 10);
}
char last = str.charAt(str.length()-1);
if(last == 'X')
   digit[digits.length-1] = 10;
else
   digit[digits.length-1] = Character.digit(last, 10);
```

(In ISBNs only the last digit can be an X.)